# IronPython: MessageQueue.Receive() exception on script

Tags: python, msmq, ironpython

I am encountering the below exception on when accessing a private queue in MSMQ, using IronPython. The exception is unexpected because (1) When I send and receive messages using the IronPython console, using the exact same commands on my script, it works,(2) The private message is actually existing (i.e. '.\private$\sample) and, (3) I already set the permission to the 'Everyone' user of the private message to full control.

Here's the snippet code I used, both in ipy console and on my script to do the receiving of message:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('System.Messaging')
from System.Messaging import *
queue_name = '.\\private$\sample'
queue = None
if MessageQueue.Exists(queue_name) = queue = MessageQueue(queue_name)
else : queue = MessageQueue.Create(queue_name)
print queue.Receive().Body   # As mentioned this works in ipy console, but not on script
```

Here's the exception:

```
System.Messaging.MessageQueueException (0x80004005): The queue does not exist or you do 
not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation.

at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.ResolveFormatNameFromQueuePath(String queuePath, 
Boolean throwException)

at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.get_FormatName()

at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.ReceiveCurrent(TimeSpan timeout, Int32 action,   
CursorHandle cursor, MessagePropertyFilter filter, MessageQueueTransaction 
internalTransaction, MessageQueueTransactionType transactionType)

at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.Receive()

at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)

at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)

at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2  
arg2)

at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, 
T1 arg1)

at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`3.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)

at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
```

Hope someone has an idea. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and the root cause was that the storage quota for MSMQ was exceeded! which doesn't seem related to the error message, which makes it a difficult cause to detect...
 To change this quota, right click on Message Queuing (from Computer management if using Windows server 2003 for example) then properties... (I cannot post images since i am a new user), but in the properties window, you will find in the first tab an editable storage limit field.

To check the currently used storage on the server, open the path of the storage, and check its size: (open the storage tab in the same properties window, and get the path of the storage folder) If the size of the quota is similar to the size of the storage folder, then this is the root cause of your issue.

If you dont have permission to increase this quota limit, you should have your user added to the "Security" tab in the message queuing properties window.

Hope this helps...